# Are formal / honorific forms mandatory when talking about oneself?

Tags: formal, honorific

If I am talking to someone superior in status or a stranger, and I refer to myself in a sentence, should formal / honorific form be used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few rules of thumb:

1. The ~시~ honorific infix (Examples: 하세요, 하십시오, 하신다...) should *only* be used if the *subject* of the clause gets honorified. A speaker shouldn't apply honorifics to himself.

   - If the *speaker* is the subject (regardless of explicitness/implicitness), he should *not* use ~시~ on that clause.
   - If the *listener* is the subject, the speaker *may* use ~시~ to apply the honorific to the listener. (And should, if as OP says, the listener is a superior/stranger)
2. Respectful speech (합쇼체 or 해요체: 합니다 or 해요) should always be used when speaking to a superior (and generally to a stranger as well) regardless of who is the subject of a sentence.

A few examples to illustrate how this would work:

- "I heard you're going."

  - (explicit reference to both parties) 저는 선생님이 가신다고 들었습니다.
  - (explicit reference to self) 저는 가신다고 들었습니다.
  - (explicit reference to listener) 가신다고 들었습니다.
  - (implied reference to both parties) 가신다고 들었습니다.

Note that the inner clause (선생님이 가신다) gets the ~시~ infix, because 선생님 is doing the 가다.

- "You heard I'm going?"

  - (explicit reference to both parties) 선생님은 제가 간다고 들으셧습니까?
  - (explicit reference to self) 제가 간다고 들으셨습니까?
  - (explicit reference to listener) 선생님은 간다고 들으셨습니까?
  - (implied reference to both parties) 간다고 들으셨습니까?

In this case, the inner clause (제가 간다) doesn't get any honorific, but 들으셨습니까 *does*, as it is the 선생님 who did the 듣다.

In both cases, it is in 합쇼체, formal respectful speech. The honorific moves around depending on whether its subject should have it applied.

Comment: Good examples. My favorite confusing example is "Please say Happy Birthday for me to your dad", talking to a friend.  
아버님께 생신 축하드린다고 전해 드려 Why this is not  아버님께 생신 축하드린다고 전해 줘 I still don't understand, to be honest.